# SilverStripe custom FormField_Holder

Tags: silverstripe

I've created a simple contact form within the page controller. For the front-end view of this contact form, I wish to use a customised `FormField_Holder` rather than the default one.

I've created a *FormField_Holder.ss* within *themes/templates/Includes*. How do I apply this template to my `$ContactForm`?

I've tried this already:

```
public function ContactForm() {

    $form = Form::create(
        ...
    );

    foreach($form->Fields() as $field) {
        $field->setFieldHolderTemplate('myHolder');
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I relocated the custom form template from
*themes/mytheme/templates/**Includes**/*
to
*themes/mytheme/templates/**forms**/*
..and it works now.

Edit: The official documentation mentions the following folder for form templates: *mysite/templates/Includes* but this oddly doesn't work oddly.
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/forms/form_templates

Comment: Includes are templates that are meant to be included via `<% include TemplateName %>`. You can put other custom templates into the main template folder or into a sub-folder (eg. forms) as you did.

Comment: I thought the same, but the official documentation says the includes folder in **mysite/includes** is the place: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/forms/form_templates/